# How do I verify whether the coefficients for my polynomal are correct?

Tags: polynomials

So, here are some values of polynomial

P(1,5) = 2
P(2) = 5
P(2,5) = -1
P(3,5) = 0,5
P(3,8) = 3
P(4,1) = 7

And here are some coefficients I got:
a1 = -673,072
a2 = 1261,5
a3 = -898,642
a4 = 307,703
a5 = -51,175
a6 = 3,33844

Thing is, a week ago someone helped me to check them and they turned out to be correct. Now I'm unable to reproduce those results. This is so frustrating and it feels like my brain just shut down. How to do it?

Comment: To which powers of the variable do the coefficients respectively correspond?

Answer (score 2):

Simply plug in the givenvalues, e.g. check if 
$$(((((3.33844\cdot 4.1+51.175)\cdot 4.1+307.703)\cdot4.1-898.642)\cdot 4.1+1261.5)\cdot4.1-673.072 \stackrel?=7$$